# Filling a JTable row with more than one list data java

Tags: swing, jtable

I'm filling a JTable dynamicaly from a list of 'steps'. Step of sort 'opening'defares from others steps, by having the posibility of containing more than one action, while all other steps type contain one action only. Therefor I would like -when reaching a step of 'open' type- to add all its actions both in same table raw like this:

```
 step name     Action     on Object  value   result
opening      full open    door1       30     ...    delete  replace
             haulgh open  door2       40            delete  replace
             wholeOpen    door1       10            delete  replace

comparison   compare      state1      ..      ...
```

where 'delete' and 'replace' are extended of JButton.
the code I've written is the following:

```
public DefaultTableModel ListToTableModel(Object[] l, String tableName) throws Exception {

    Vector<String> columnNames = null;
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<>();
    columnNames = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(" Step name:  ","  Action: ","  On object: ","  Action value: "," Action result: ","                          ","                              "));
    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<((Step) l[i]).action.size();j++){
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
            String string="";int k=0;
            if(((Step) l[i]).Name=="opening"){
                 vector.add(((Step) l[i]).Name);

                 for(k=0;k<((Step) l[i]).action.size();k++){
                     string+=((Step) l[i]).action.get(k)+"\n";
                 }
                 vector.add(string);
                 string="";

                 for( k=0;k<((Step) l[i]).onObject.size();k++){
                     string+=((Step) l[i]).onObject.get(k)+"\n";
                 }
                 vector.add(string);
                 string="";

                 for(k=0;k<((Step) l[i]).value.size();k++){
                     string+=((Step) l[i]).value.get(k)+"\n";
                 }
                 vector.add(string);
                 string="";

                 for( k=0;k<((Step) l[i]).result.size();k++){
                     string+=((Step) l[i]).result.get(k)+"\n";
                 }
                 vector.add(string);
                 break;
            }
            else
            {
                vector.add(((Step) l[i]).Name);
                vector.add(((Step) l[i]).action.get(j));
                vector.add(((Step) l[i]).onObject.get(j));
                vector.add(((Step) l[i]).value.get(j));
                vector.add(((Step) l[i]).result.get(j));
                vector.add("delete");
                vector.add("Replace");
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
            return true;
        }

    };
}
```

and Step class is:

```
public class Step {
public String Name=null;
public List<String> action=null;
public List<String> onObject=null;
public List<String> value=null;
public List<String> result=null;

public Step(String n){
    Name=n;
    action=new ArrayList<String>();
    onObject=new ArrayList<String>();
    value=new ArrayList<String>();
    result=new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void add(String act,String onobject ,String val,String res){
    action.add(act);
    onObject.add(onobject);
    value.add(val);
    result.add(res);
}
```

but the only result I get when calling:

```
Step step=new Step("opening");
    step.add("full open","door1","30.0","door_1");
    step.add("haulgh open","door2","40.0","door_2");
    step.add("whole open","door3","40.0","door_3");
           Controller.getStepList().add(step);

    step=new Step("comparison");
    step.add("compare","state1","--","state_1");
       Controller.getStepList().add(step);
```

is:

```
step name  Action   on Object  value  result
comparison  compare  state1      --    state_1
```

Does anyOne have an idea whats wrong with it?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it.
When reaching an "oppening" step type,  index j from the external loop points to the step's action list. but in the internal loop k runs over the action list by itself and ends by adding the string to the raw. The prob is that J is continuing to run over the right same action list, in next loops..so in the last final loop the string contains just nothing..

My way of resolving the prob is by changing the Step class stracture to contain the whole step data in one uniq string, and then I just fill the 'oppening' step data in the same way as all other steps type with no inner loop. I know it could be a better way for resolving it, but changing the Step class stracture is needed for me for some other reasons, so I take advantage of it..